# How to pass forwardRef through route when using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Let's say I have 2 components, app and project

I want to have control of elements in my project component from my app component.

When not using a route I can just do the following in my app component

```
const App = () => {

  const ProjectRef = useRef(null);
  
  return (
  
   <Project ref={projectRef}>

  );
}
```

Then in my project component I can get the reference as such

```
const Project = ({}, ref) => {}
```

My issue is how to achieve this when using a route. I have tried the following in my app.js component:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/projects/:slug">
      <Project ref={projectRef}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

This works in that I can get the ref, however in this method I can't seem to get access to the information about the route, which I need for this dynamic route.

Previously I did the following to get the slug

```
const Project = ({ match, location }) => {
  // Get slug
  const {params: { slug }} = match;
}
```

I tried the following, but it does not work, match is empty.

```
const Project = ({ match, location }, ref) => {}
```

I am looking for a way to achieve this ideally with functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the router `props` to the defined router component `Project`. So, just passing props to the component should do the work in your case.

Just replace this

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/projects/:slug">
      <Project ref={projectRef}/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

with this

```
  <Switch>
    <Route
       path="/projects/:slug"
       render={(props) => <Project {...props} ref={projectRef} />}
    />
  </Switch>
```